# Why is the inductive effect of σ-electrons only along saturated carbon chains?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

In my book the following is written:

> When an electron withdrawing atom such as a halogen is attached to the end of a carbon chain, the $\sigma$-electrons of the $\ce{C-X}$ bond are attached to or displaced towards the more electronegative halogen atom, as a result $\ce{X}$ acquires a small negative charge and $\ce{C_1}$ acquires a small positive charge. The small positive charge on the $\ce{C_1}$ in turn attracts the $\sigma$-electrons of the $\ce{C_1-C_2}$ bond towards it. As a result $\ce{C_2}$ acquires a small charge, of course smaller than on $\ce{C_1}$.

Then as $\ce{C_2}$ acquires a small a charge shouldn't the positive charge of $\ce{C_1}$ become less than earlier? Shouldn't it be true?

> ...This type of a displacement of $\sigma$-electrons along a saturated carbon chain whenever an electron withdrawing group is present the end of the chain is called inductive effect.

Why is there displacement of only $\sigma$-electrons not $\pi$-electrons and why does it happen along a saturated carbon chain only?

Comment: Your, right in 1 case and it seems to me your over interpreting this - it's only an example and inductive effect affects all bonds, but there may be stronger mesomeric effects

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the inductive effect is applicable only on sigma electrons and not pi electrons is because sigma bonds are stronger and more stable than pi bonds. Sigma bonds involve head-on overlapping of orbitals, so the electrons in these bonds are more likely to stay in place. This allows the inductive effect to propagate along a chain of atoms connected by sigma bonds3.

On the other hand, pi bonds involve side-on overlapping of orbitals and the electron density is spread out above and below the plane of the atoms. This makes the electrons in pi bonds more mobile and less likely to stay in one place, which is why the inductive effect does not apply to them